error when running tests from nunit-console
I have a very simple test that looks like this.
 [Test]
 public void TestConnection()
 {
     var connectionString = "valid value for connectionstring";
     var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
     connection.Open();
 }

When I run this from Visual Studio using resharper everything works ok.
But when I tries to run this test from nunit3-console.exe I get the following error.
System.TypeInitializationException : The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser' threw an exception.
  ----> System.TypeInitializationException : The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNILoadHandle' threw an exception.
  ----> System.DllNotFoundException : Unable to load DLL 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.dll' or one of its dependencies: The specified module could not be found. (0x8007007E)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser..ctor(Boolean MARS, Boolean fAsynchronous)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, String accessToken, DbConnectionPool pool, Func`3 accessTokenCallback)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)

Im using Nunit 4.1.0 and NUnit.Console-3.17.0. Have tried with older versions of nunit but same result. The project is built using .net8.
Any suggestions?
The Console runner I have tested to run this with.
https://github.com/nunit/nunit-console/releases/tag/3.17.0
The csproj
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
    </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Data.SqlClient" Version="5.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets" Version="6.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="17.9.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit" Version="4.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>

Sample project with test containers that gives me the same result.
https://github.com/pahe/Nunit-Console

"But when I tries to run this test from nunit3-console.exe" - are you trying this on the same machine? Do you have a [mre]?

Same machine
Updated the post with a mre.

I think I have kind of solved it. If I copies the file Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.dll into the bin folder of the console runner it works. Not sure this is the best solution but it works right now.
